# How to create a custom radio button with dictionary input for .Net core

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I am using .NET core forms designer (Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.7.3), I want to populate a group of radio buttons with a dictionary (key and value).  And if I click select any one radio button, I will get the dictionary entry including key and value.
The following is my code now:

```
        public static Dictionary<int, string> Dict_Names()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> D2Name = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "Name 1" },
            { 2, "Name 2" },
            { 3, "Name 3" },
        };
        return(D2Name);
    }

    private void CreateRadioButton(Dictionary<int, string> dict1)
    {
        int base_x = 50;
        int base_y = 50;
        var radioButtons = new RadioButton[dict1.Count()];
        var button_group = dict1.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < button_group.Length; ++i)
        {
            radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton
            {
                Text = Convert.ToString(button_group[i].Value),
                Location = new Point(base_x, base_y + 20 * i),
                Size = new Size(200, 20)
            };
            this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
        }
    }
```

I can see those radio buttons displayed on the screen.  But how I can get the value selected.  I don’t want to add another control like a button to click.  I wish if I can create a custom radio button class, I can input the dictionary and get the selected radio button value back.
Please advice.

Comment: Why don't u use a CheckedChanged even handler? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You probably want a `Dictionary<RadioButton, class>` or `Dictionary<RadioButton, Action>` or `Dictionary<RadioButton, Func<something>>` instead. When a RadioButton is selected, you can easily activate the related Action, Func or get the associated class object, since the RadioButton object is the Dictionary Key. In any event related to your RadioButtons, the `sender` object is the RadioButton that raised the event. Just cast it.

Comment: I don't know how to use Dictionary<RadioButton, class> or Dictionary<RadioButton, Action>. Do you have any code sample or some web links, so I can take a look.